# javascript toFixed(2) not working in calculations

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I have a bit of code that involves calculations that I'm trying to show only two decimals. I'm using .toFixed(2), but its still not working. Am I putting it in the right spot?

```
   function SetFoodItems(amount) {
    // returns the amount in the .99 format
    return amount == Math.floor(amount)) ? amount + '.00' : ((amount * 10 
   == Math.floor(amount * 10)) ? amount + '0';
   }

  function SelectFoodItems(form) {
    var UpdateCosts = (form.quantity.value - 0) * (form.unitcost.value - 
 0) + (form.quantity1.value - 0) * (form.unitcost1.value - 0) + 
(form.quantity2.value - 0) * (form.unitcost2.value - 0) + 
(form.quantity3.value - 0) * (form.unitcost3.value - 0).toFixed(2);

    UpdateCosts = Math.floor(subtotal * 1000) / 1000;
    form.subtotal.value = '$' + SetFoodItems(subtotal).toFixed(2);

    var tax = (UpdateCosts / 100 * (form.rate.value - 0).toFixed(2);
    tax = Math.floor(tax * 1000) / 1000;
    form.tax.value = '$' + SetFoodItems(tax);

    total = UpdateCosts + tax;
    total = Math.floor((total * 1000) / 1000);
   form.total.value = '$' + SetFoodItems(total).toFixed(2;
```

Comment: The `.toFixed()` function returns a **string**, not a number. When you use it in calculations (like the tax formula) it's converted back to a number. All JavaScript numbers (well except for the new big integer type) are binary floating-point values and really unsuited for "money math".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, your `.toFixed()` method returns a string; the reason being of type conversions. For example, the addition with a string `1 + "0"` converts 1 to a string so you get `10` as a string. You can find more information about it if you search online.

Now that you know that; to solve your problem you can use different options. Up to you which one you like best depending on what you want your code to return:

- `parseInt('your-number-string').toFixed(2)`
- `parseFloat('your-number-string').toFixed(2)`
- `Number('your-number-string').toFixed(2)`

Any of these will give you a number.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks @Dharman I will look into the info. I will delete my reply as well. Just thought I'd reply.